# Aether lens for Blink dagger

Tags: dota-2

Does the item *Aether Lens* have any effect on the range of *Blink Dagger* or *Force Staff*?

The default range for *Blink Dagger* is 1200, so does *Aether Lens* increase that to 1400?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the cast ranges for all items are increased by 200.

Comment: How does it interact with blink dagger's "Clicked-too-far-so-you-teleport-a-shorter-distance-instead" range?

Comment: @user1337 The same, you go 80% of 1400 instead of 80% of 1200.